# Java creating instance of a map object

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, dictionary

Really simple question hopefully. I want to do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> temp = { colName, data };
```

Where `colName`, `data` are string variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Even though it's not available now, I believe this will land in Java 8 unless they dropped it when I wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Map is an interface.  Create an instance of one the classes that implements it:

```
Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
temp.put(colName, data);
```

Or, in Java 7:

```
Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
temp.put(colName, data);
```

Comment: can you explain why in java7 is that possible?

Comment: In Java 7, support was added for omitting the types in certain cases.  It's just to make the code a little cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

@JohnGirata is correct.

If you're REALLY upset, you could have a look here http://nileshbansal.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/initializing-java-maps-inline.html

It's not quite what you're asking, but is a neat trick/hack non the less.

Answer (score 2):

The quick way of putting entries in a `Map` just created is the following (let me use a HashMap 'cause I like them):

```
Map<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>(){{
    put(colName, data);
}};
```

Note all those parenthesis with a closing semicolon!

While it's true that in `Java7` you can generally use the `diamond operator` and write something like this `Map<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();`, this does not work when putting elements in the Map inline. In other words, the compiler with yell at you if you try the following (don't ask me why):

```
Map<String,String> temp = new HashMap<>(){{
    put(colName, data);
}};
```